# Understanding how to return list.reduceLeft

Tags: scala

I have the following method where I want to return a map by performing a reduceLeft on a list.  My issue is that occasionally the list is empty so Im not sure the correct way to deal with that:

```
  def results(start: String, end: String) = {
    val iter = new QueryIterator(RK, start, end);

    val list = for (hcol <- iter) yield (Map(hcol.getValue() -> 
        Map(hcol.getName()) -> hcol.getTime()))))
    list.reduceLeft(_ ++ _)
  }
```

When the list is empty it throws an exception that stops the execution.  What is the best way to get around this problem?

Comment: That is exactly what `reduceLeft` does. It works off from the head of the input list and throws exception when list is empty. Use `foldLeft` instead, as Rex says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `foldLeft` instead and start with an empty map of the type that you want to return, e.g.

```
list.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int,(String,Float)])(_ ++ _)
```

(Make sure you properly match the type of the map; I'm guessing that `getValue()` returns an `Int`, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

If that's confusing you could do it imperative stylee (but don't tell anyone I told you)

```
var m = Map[Int,(String,Float)]()
new QueryIterator(RK, start, end) foreach { hcol => 
  m += Map(hcol.getValue -> Map(hcol.getName -> hcol.getTime)) 
}
m
```

Comment: Should perhaps also have mentioned that this is quite a bit more efficient than mapping to another list then folding...

Comment: A sufficiently smart compiler could fuse the map-then-fold to be just as efficient. I'm not sure how smart the Scala compiler for the JVM actually is about this, though.

Comment: @DanBurton I doubt the compiler is that smart, but in OP's case he's using (presumably) an `Iterator` so actually mapping then folding is efficient, since a mapped iterator is still lazy. If it were a `List` he could use a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.sum` method from Scalaz.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> List(Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4), Map(4 -> 11)).asMA.sum
res21: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 11)

scala> (Nil : List[Map[Int, Int]]).asMA.sum
res22: Map[Int,Int] = Map()
```

Comment: `.asMA` turns the List into a "monoid", amirite? See, I have learnt something from this site.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge, no, that's not so. `List` already has a method `.sum`. We want to invoke the one provided by Scalaz, hence we need to explicitly convert `List` to `MA` (the Scalaz extension-class for types of kind `* -> *`) using the method `.asMA`.